# Calling api when button is clicked

Tags: android, api, android-studio

Hello everyone i am trying to make an app which returns the result from an api into my text view which is in my activity right now i just click on the button and the onclick listener should start working but the problem is that it is not returning anything here is the code:-
package com.example.youtubehub;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class Download_Page extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button download_button;
    EditText editText;
    String full_url, receive_url,title;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_page);
        download_button = findViewById(R.id.download_button_1);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        download_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                load_page();
            }
        });
//
    }
        public void load_page()  {
            String url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                String answer = response.getString("title");
                                textView.setText(answer);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.d("scuess", "onResponse: ");

                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {



                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO: Handle error

                        }
                    });





    }}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug?  Are you getting a response from the server?  Is the response formatted as expected?  Are you getting a networking error?  You need to use a debugger and see what's happening.

Comment: debugger is not returning anything as far as i can understand.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to check whether you have added Internet permission on your Android Manifest file like below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Once that is set and done I noticed that you are using volley correctly but the problem is that you are not creating a `RequestQueue` and passing it the `jsonObjectRequest` as per the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple)

To Show you how it will work refine your load_page() method as below and it will work

```
 public void load_page() {
    String url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView4);//remove this. already defined on onCreate

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);//create a request Queue and pass the context of the activity

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String answer = response.getString("title");
                        textView.setText(answer);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("scuess", "onResponse: ");

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {


                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }
            });


    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest); //pass the jsonObjectRequest

}
```

Read more on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple)

Comment: Thanks man it is working perfectly fine when i used your way but there is still a problem , the api i used in this question is not the one i want to use in my app this was just a sample one to just test it , now when i tried to use my original one it is not showing any results maybe because it take 2-3 minutes to show results even on browser so i am not sure how can i overcome this problem in android. here is the original api :- https://anroidyt.herokuapp.com/url/?url=https://youtu.be/t_xrBpg-1Zs

Comment: Hey, the link above is not working,kindly repost it

Comment: @Spidy The concept still applies when using Volley, that is the best way to do it but if you receive slow requests then you should work on your API and try to Optimize it a bit

Comment: isnt there any way to make volley wait?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant really help you there because am not familiar with how to do that. Best way I know how is to just optimize the API

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted, thank you @Spidy

Comment: Sorry for late reply  i dont know how to mark the answer as accepted also please tell me how to optimize the Api i am facing too much problem in it as it gets timed out again and again my api is in python using flask and i used selenium inside my api @Mosericko